# .Net Framework Entity Framework: How to avoid inner select?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework for the following:
Get the latest row where some columns are equal to X and Y. The LINQ looks like this (I have also tried to rewrite it as "FROM WHERE" statement, among other things, to no avail):

```
var logEvent = Context.Set<Log>().Where(e =>
            e.Id == id && e.MessageType == messageType)
            .OrderByDescending(e => e.DateTime)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

I would expect this to generate the following:

```
SELECT TOP (1) *
FROM [dbo].[Log]
WHERE [Log].[Id] = @p__linq__0
AND [Log].[MessageType] = @p__linq__1
ORDER BY [Log].[DateTime] DESC
```

Instead it generates an inner Select that just iterates over the whole table, and the pick TOP 1 from the ordered rows.
(I have indexed DateTime and Id)

```
SELECT TOP (1) *
    FROM ( SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].[Log] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0)
        AND ([Extent1].[MessageType] = @p__linq__1)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[DateTime] DESC
GO
```

What is causing this inner SELECT?

Comment: I would *guess* that it's how they chose to implement their linq-to-sql. It easily allows to select some specific columns and do more complex thing in your EF query, (that would be reflected in the inner select), while the `select top(1) * `  is just the translation of the `FirstOrDefault`. However, is there any actual *issue* you are experiencing ? Or is it just out of curiosity ? EF (non-core) is closed source, one might decompile and explain the code, but the root design reason might be info only available to the EF dev team.

Comment: how did you get the query? is it using SQL Profiler? what happens if you reorder your query to be `Context.Set<Log>().OrderByDescending(e => e.DateTime).FirstOrDefault(x => e.Id == id && e.MessageType == messageType)` does it result the same query? Entit Frameworks aims to make query easier to be written on code.. though it may sacrifice performance on some cases.

Comment: In SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. Especially, the system isn't stupid enough to "iterates over the whole table" of the subselect before it limits itself to one row. We'd expect both of your SQL queries to generate near-identical execution plans.

Comment: exactly as Damin_The_Unbeliever said, there is no problem *per se* with this request. That is just *not* how a *human* would have written it, but apart from that you have nothing to worry. (Well... you will worry when you see really bad-performing EF-generated request, but this is not one of them ;) )

Comment: (please share the SQL-Server execution plan for further discussion on how the query is performing)

Comment: Your expected query would be the result if you'd use `First()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

*FirstOrDefault()* is the reason of translating LINQ query into SELECT TOP (1) FROM (another select)

Comment: Could you add some more information on this? (How, why, sources)

Answer (score 0):

@Bagus Tesa directed me to the correct answer. Thank you all.

Doing the `OrderBy()` FIRST was the solution.
The following LINQ query generates the expected query:

```
var logEvent = Context.Set<Log>()
.OrderByDescending(e => e.DateTime)
.FirstOrDefault(e => (e.Id == id) && e.MessageType == messageType));
```

I also tested in case I wanted more than 1 result row:

```
var importLogEvent1 = Context.Set<ImportLog>()
.OrderByDescending(e => e.DateTime)
.Where(e => (e.Id == id) && e.MessageType == messageType))
.Take(5);
```

This also generated a "clean" SQL query.

NOTE: As some have pointed out, the generated SQL query even though it looked "bad", might very well have resulted in a equally good execution plan. I did not look into this.